# awk throwing error "wk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN blocks must have an action part"

Tags: linux, bash, awk, centos, centos6

I wrote this test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

build_message='build'

# On first run, the supplied settings block is appended to the supplied config
# file surrounded by comments ("# build START" and "# build END").
# On subsequent runs, the lines in between the two comments will be replaced
# by the provided settings block.
config-insert () {
    settings="$1"
    file="$2"
    awk='BEGIN { p = 1; o = 1; }
        $0 ~ "^# " m " START" { p = 0; if (o) output(); o = 0; }
        $0 ~ "^# " m " END"{ p = 1; next }
        END { if (o) output(o); }
        { if (p) print $0; }
        function output() { print "# " m " START\n" s "\n# " m " END"; }'
    awk -v m="$build_message" -v s="$settings" $awk $file > $file
}

config-insert "setting block" testfile
```

When I run it, I get a weird error:

> awk: cmd. line:1: BEGIN blocks must have an action part

Comment: Any particular reasons you want to write `awk` like that? `awk` is not `bash` and does not conform to expansions you'd expect in bash. Also, note that you are redirecting the output of a file to the same file.

Comment: Like what? How would you write it?

Comment: I cannot write code looking at the code. If you can put some sample input data and your expected output, then may be I can.

Comment: @JS웃 I'm not asking you to rewrite the code. My question is, when you said "Any particular reasons you want to write awk like that?", what aspect of the way I wrote awk are you referring to?

Comment: Assigning `awk` syntax to a variable called `awk` and then calling that variable inside `awk` is what I was referring to.

Comment: @JS웃 What's the real difference between that and doing something like `awk "awkscript" file`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $awk in quotes:

```
awk -v m="$build_message" -v s="$settings" "$awk" "$file"
```

Comment: Not in _single quotes_, please.

Comment: Double quotes make a single parameter with the entire value of `$awk`. Single quotes make a single string whose value is literally `$awk`. No quotes make a series of parameters for each word in the value of `$awk`.

Answer (score 2):

The shell is eating your quotes.   Typically when I get to problems like this with awk/bash/sed scripting  I resort to a temp file.

```
    ...
    tempfile=$(mktemp)
    echo ${awk} >${tempfile}       
    awk ...  -f ${tempfile} ...
    rm ${tempfile}
```

Depending on degree of security you want,  you might use mktemp to make the directory rather than the file.